# ogr2ogr PDF unable to open datasource but PDF is recognized fine in GDALInfo

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, geospatial-pdf, geopdf, gdalinfo

I am attempting to use ogr2ogr to convert a PDF to a SHP through the OSGeo4W shell, part of the QGIS installation (3.6 i think) on windows 10.  I have used this before successfully but been a while so unsure why it isn't working.  I have tried using 2 PDFs (both georeferenced - i can see the latlong).  Both PDFs are recognized in GDALInfo and all the info is provided easily.

When run in ogr2ogr i use the simple following line:

```
ogr2ogr dest.shp source.pdf
```

but get this error

```
Unable to open datasource `source.pdf' with the following drivers.
  -> `JP2ECW'
  -> `OCI'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
```

It has the PDF driver (which works fine in GDALInfo) so why not here?

Both PDFs were made in ArcMap.  When exporting PDFs I know the georeference option needs to be checked for this to work.  I also found that only the middle option "Export PDF Layers Only" works in ogr2ogr.  If either the  flattened version "None" and the "Export PDF Layers and Feature Attributes" are chosen then the ogr2ogr conversion does not work.  I cant see a way around this

Examples PDFs here if you want to see.  Only GeoPDF2.pdf seems to work in OGR2OGR.
https://we.tl/t-xBBRCJg9TH

[image: ArcMap Export Map options]

Comment: gdalinfo is giving you information about a **raster** and `ogr2ogr` is trying to open a **vector**

Comment: PDF can be either raster https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/pdf.html or vector https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pdf.html#vector-pdf or even both at the same time. If you could convert similar PDF files before there may be some regression.

Comment: OK thanks both - the PDF will contain some raster and vector data

Comment: although it is just the vector data that i need

Comment: then better use ogrinfo instead of gdalinfo to check the available data.

Comment: Tried that and  get same response "Unable to open datasource...."

Comment: I am guessing it is an issue with the PDF driver being unable to open that type of PDF?

Comment: Sample file would be appreciated. If your real files are confidential try to find some other file that shows the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this partially by adding the command:
`ogr2ogr CG.shp CG.pdf --config OGR_PDF_READ_NON_STRUCTURED YES`
It created a georeferenced linear shapefile of all the features.